# R density plot (edge effects and showing counts in the y-axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have been using variations of the following code for quite a while, but now I am working with a very small dataset (28 rows) and that gives me two different problems: the first one is that the edge effects seem to be massive doesn't matter what kernel I use. The second one is not exactly a problem, but for what I am trying to do now it would be convenient to be able to show counts instead of density in the y-axis. I know it can be done as I have seen density plots without edge effect problems (or at least they are not that apparent) and with counts in the y-axis in publications. I have been looking at how to solve my problems for days and either I have found nothing or I have not been able to implement what I have found. It seems that my problems would be easier to solve if I were using ggplot2, but a part of the code was made by a former teacher of mine and I just don't how to reproduce what he did in ggplot2. Anyway, here is my code:

```
bw = 500
y <- density(check$sim, bw = bw, n=512, kernel = "gaussian", weights = burialsToRun$Weight)
ymax=0.010

par(mar=c(4.1,2.1,2.1,6.1))
plot(y, xlim = c(-9500, -3500), xaxs = "i", ylim = c(0, ymax), main="", col = rgb(0,0,0,0.05), axes = FALSE, ylab = " ", xlab = " ")
axis(1, at=seq(-9500, -3500, by = 500), las = 1)
axis(4, at=seq(0, ymax, by = 0.001), las = 1)
mtext(text="Density", side=4, line=4, las=3) 
mtext(text="Calibrated date (cal. BC)", side=1, line=2.5, las=1)
box() # para meter mi gráfico en una cajita

for(i in 1:3000) {
  burialsToRun[, sim := {x <- runif(nrow(burialsToRun)); (x * (End - Start)) + Start}]
  check <- burialsToRun[, list(Start, End, sim)]
  y <- density(check$sim, bw = bw, n=512, kernel = "gaussian", weights = burialsToRun$Weight)
  lines(y, col= rgb(0,0,0,0.05))
}
```

Data:

```
check <- structure(list(Start = c(-7060, -8174, -7530, -5300, -5300, -5881, 
-5600, -5600, -7000, -9300, -9200, -9300, -9300, -6200, -4240, 
-4240, -4240, -4240, -4240, -4240, -8999, -5208, -5979, -5476, 
-5979, -5630, -5470, -5979), End = c(-6246, -7833, -7201, -3950, 
-3950, -5747, -5000, -5000, -5500, -9200, -8300, -8500, -8300, 
-5600, -3480, -3480, -3480, -3480, -3480, -3480, -5000, -4840, 
-4333, -5029, -4333, -4333, -4452, -5533), sim = c(-6407.1891290769, 
-7845.75364494463, -7345.1619859545, -4872.66194844851, -4995.94754445134, 
-5802.87022047071, -5151.49392490275, -5135.55407933891, -6972.37427707296, 
-9291.56357476022, -8720.51239821594, -8767.55619421601, -9271.44779283553, 
-6083.65002772771, -4060.82516569644, -3753.49776098505, -4222.84405510873, 
-4165.94615798444, -4007.33239018358, -4069.03453745879, -5708.78666541586, 
-5171.84607211128, -5616.71954697417, -5134.90122210816, -5173.40105968062, 
-4721.55411865073, -4935.3219843721, -5927.93708416494)), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

burialsToRun <- structure(list(Burial = 1:28, Start = c(-7060, -8174, -7530, 
-5300, -5300, -5881, -5600, -5600, -7000, -9300, -9200, -9300, 
-9300, -6200, -4240, -4240, -4240, -4240, -4240, -4240, -8999, 
-5208, -5979, -5476, -5979, -5630, -5470, -5979), End = c(-6246, 
-7833, -7201, -3950, -3950, -5747, -5000, -5000, -5500, -9200, 
-8300, -8500, -8300, -5600, -3480, -3480, -3480, -3480, -3480, 
-3480, -5000, -4840, -4333, -5029, -4333, -4333, -4452, -5533
), Weight = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), sim = c(-6804.49034169316, -7978.35553480918, -7266.07094835793, 
-5021.92656769184, -3969.11897005048, -5871.17116243485, -5130.67335872911, 
-5569.97352014296, -5871.00151088089, -9211.72905953135, -8927.66143891495, 
-8923.21154009551, -9210.72582732886, -5775.25383243337, -3504.35795384459, 
-3780.76538468711, -4138.03785683587, -3826.4371876698, -3882.20702474937, 
-4058.1953032501, -5341.79313169955, -4980.0766399838, -4356.67793130036, 
-5386.85334781208, -5036.12725707935, -5213.0496873688, -4550.98105533235, 
-5877.78668494383)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Since the solutions I found were for ggplot2, what I have been trying is, first of all, to make the same plot in ggplot2.

```
ggplot(check, aes(sim, after_stat(count))) + 
stat_density(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "line", position = "stack", bw = 500, adjust = 1, kernel = "gaussian", trim = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE, bounds = c(-9500, -3500), orientation = NA, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) +
  xlim(-9500, -3500) +
  xlab("Calibrated date (cal. BC)") +
  ylab("Count") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "lines")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-9500, -3500, by = 1000)) +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right")
```

As you can see, I did not get far and what I did is probably wrong. I certainly do not know how to make the 3000 repetitions I need.

I would prefer if the problems could be directly solved using the plot function rather than ggplot2, since I am used to that one. However, if that is not possible I would be glad if someone could explain how to make the 3000 repetitions in ggplot2. Also, please, point if there is something wrong with what I already made. I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very difficult to help without your data. Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(check)`? Thanks

Comment: @Alijaba thanks - but now I have realised I still can't run your code because I don't have `burialsToRun`

Comment: @AllanCameron done again!